# Speed of retrieving dictionary items with try...except vs. key in dict?

Tags: python, performance

I frequently need to check if a key is in a dictionary, then do something else if it is not. In python, there are two clear ways to do this:

```py
if key in dict_:
   value = dict_[key]
   do_something
else:
   do_something_else
```

or

```py
try:
    value = dict_[key]
except KeyError:
    do_something_else
else:
    do_something
```

Which of these is faster/preferable? Does it depend on the dictionary size?

It seems there may be two competing effects here: 1) having to search for a key twice, vs. 2) setting up an exception stack trace.

Comment: Hash map look ups are O(1). If you don't want to raise an exception I would go with first. If you are really concerned about that time I think a `defaultdict` from the `collections` module could help you out.

Comment: @ericstevens26101 `defaultdict` probably is not what you want if you are hoping to `do_something_else` when the value is not in the dictionary.

Comment: Also, `dict`s in python are no longer just hashmaps ;). They are b-trees-ish for performance and ordering reasons. The theoretical complexity and practical complexity are going to be different here.

Comment: @modesitt no, absolutely not, they are (fancy) hashmaps. They are absolutely not b-trees.

Comment: That was what I recalled was used for order preservation over the table - the "fancy" part. [Here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-December/123028.html) is the tldr of the implementation. This is why i said "no longer just' @juanpa.arrivillaga. I did not say "they are not"...

Comment: They are hash tables + links for ordering.. access is still O(1). A B-tree implementation would change that and break expectations.

Comment: @modesitt yes, I know, but that doesn't describe a B-tree. In any case, B-trees keep items in *sorted* order, not in insertion order (I suppose, you *could* use some sort of sorting key which is just the insertion order...). You can read a high-level overview directly in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c), note, the first line is a comment `/* Dictionary object implementation using a hash table */`

Comment: I just miss-though nodes contained the key's values *and* indexes were used to order nodes. I just thought a b-tree was used on top of the map for keys as the real-time sorting of insert. My main point was big-O here is less meaningful than a performance benchmark as the overhead of `try/except`, the implementation of `.get`, etc are what **actually** matter here instead of a non-contributing conversation about `O(...)` to a practical question.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Depending on the use case, using a default dict would return something that would evaluate to False in an if statement: `if d['bad_key']: do_something_else`, then the `do_something_else` could be performed as a result of the if statement, faster than looking up the key again in a large dict according to everyone above.

Answer (score 3):

You can benchmark three different methods with [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html). `get1` is the `try...except`, `get2` uses the builtin `.get`, and `get3` first checks.

```
In [1]: def get1(d, k): 
......:     try: 
......:         return d[k] 
......:     except KeyError: 
......:         return None 

In [3]: def get2(d, k): 
......:     return d.get(k) 

In [4]: def get3(d, k): 
......:    if k in d: return d[k]  
......:    else: return None
```

> On a small dictionary (100 elements)

```
In [8]: %timeit -n 100 [get1(little_d, e) for e in range(len(little_d))]                
18.8 µs ± 270 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [9]: %timeit -n 100 [get2(little_d, e) for e in range(len(little_d))]                
22.5 µs ± 352 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit -n 100 [get3(little_d, e) for e in range(len(little_d))]               
19.3 µs ± 862 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

> And a bigger one (1M elements)

```
In [11]: %timeit -n 100 [get1(big_d, e) for e in range(len(little_d))]
19.4 µs ± 469 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit -n 100 [get2(big_d, e) for e in range(len(little_d))]
21.8 µs ± 241 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [13]: %timeit -n 100 [get3(big_d, e) for e in range(len(little_d))]
19.2 µs ± 128 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

> On a (1M) dictionary with ~50% "misses" (`random.choices(range(0, 2*len(big_id)), k=len(big_d))`) shows more difference:

```
In [20]: %timeit -n 100 [get1(big_d, e) for e in choices]                              
514 ms ± 10.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit -n 100 [get2(big_d, e) for e in choices]                              
416 ms ± 4.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [22]: %timeit -n 100 [get3(big_d, e) for e in choices]                              
367 ms ± 4.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

`.get` will still be faster in this case.

```
In [23]: %timeit -n 100 [big_id.get(e) for e in choices]                                
334 ms ± 3.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

They seem close, equally impacted by the size of the dictionary, but differently effected by misses. The only real impacts size is going to have is when python begins [thrashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031902/what-is-thrashing-why-does-it-occur) (as it probably? does here). An important note is that `get2` is simply slower because the induced overhead of two function calls (`get2` and `.get`) which are expensive-ish in python (as shown in the last test). The misses will result in slower results for a variety of reasons as *@user2864740* points out.

#### tl;dr

I would use `.get`.

---

The answer will also largely depend on the speed of the `__hash__` and `__eq__` implementation of your keys. If `__hash__` and `__eq__` are slow, the differences of two calls to `hash` may show making method 1 or 2 (without the extra function) better.

Comment: Does the behavior change on “mostly misses” (ie. lots of errors raised)? I would expect that it does due to stack unwinding and additional overhead.

Comment: hmmm, method 3 does not return the value, just the dict itself.  should be `return d[k]`.  whats the speed then?

Comment: nice catch @JLPeyret, I updated the timing results - The ordering happened to stay the same though (despite the typo invalidating `.get3`).