# Does cudaHostAllocMapped also allocate a buffer on the device?

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, pci-e

[The documentation](http://horacio9573.no-ip.org/cuda/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g15a3871f15f8c38f5b7190946845758c.html) for `cudaHostAlloc()` says that with `cudaHostAllocMapped` flag it allocates pinned memory on the host and "Maps the allocation into the CUDA address space". Does it mean that a mirror buffer is allocated on the device too? Either during `cudaHostAlloc()` or `cudaHostGetDevicePointer()` call.
Or does the device communicate with the host memory upon each access to the pointer returned by `cudaHostGetDevicePointer()` ?

This question is different from [When to use cudaHostRegister() and cudaHostAlloc()? What is the meaning of "Pinned or page-locked" memory? Which are the equivalent in OpenCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454465/when-to-use-cudahostregister-and-cudahostalloc-what-is-the-meaning-of-pinn) because I don't ask what the APIs are, when to use them or what is pinned memory. I ask specifically whether a mirror buffer is allocated on GPU or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use cudaHostRegister() and cudaHostAlloc()? What is the meaning of "Pinned or page-locked" memory? Which are the equivalent in OpenCL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454465/when-to-use-cudahostregister-and-cudahostalloc-what-is-the-meaning-of-pinn)

Comment: @Leos313, there is nothing in that question or answers about the mirror buffer. I already knew the answers for that question. I am interested in the details on how GPU accesses CPU memory.

Comment: No memory is allocated on the device, all accesses go to host memory. [This documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#mapped-memory) may be better suited for your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No "mirror"  buffer is allocated.

When device code uses a pointer that refers to mapped host memory, then a device read or write using that pointer will generated PCIE traffic to transfer the data to/from host memory, to service that read or write.