# Purpose of `use_host_ptr` property in SYCL

Tags: sycl

What is the point of `use_host_ptr` property in SYCL?
Why will the SYCL runtime not use the memory pointed to by the provided host pointer?
https://registry.khronos.org/SYCL/specs/sycl-2020/html/sycl-2020.html#sec:buffer-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A runtime might prefer to allocate [pinned / page-locked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5736968/929437), or just better aligned memory to speed-up copies between host and device.

For example, [Intel DPC++ allocates the temporary buffer if the supplied pointer does not have the required alignment](https://github.com/intel/llvm/blob/5801970585b2724dae8367470152304cd2718e3c/sycl/source/detail/sycl_mem_obj_t.hpp#L171-L200):

```cpp
  bool useHostPtr() {
    return has_property<property::buffer::use_host_ptr>() ||
           has_property<property::image::use_host_ptr>();
  }

  bool canReuseHostPtr(void *HostPtr, const size_t RequiredAlign) {
    bool Aligned =
        (reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(HostPtr) % RequiredAlign) == 0;
    return !MHostPtrReadOnly && (Aligned || useHostPtr());
  }

  void handleHostData(void *HostPtr, const size_t RequiredAlign) {
    MHostPtrProvided = true;
    if (!MHostPtrReadOnly && HostPtr) {
      set_final_data([HostPtr](const std::function<void(void *const Ptr)> &F) {
        F(HostPtr);
      });
    }

    if (HostPtr) {
      if (canReuseHostPtr(HostPtr, RequiredAlign)) {
        MUserPtr = HostPtr;
      } else {
        setAlign(RequiredAlign);
        MShadowCopy = allocateHostMem();
        MUserPtr = MShadowCopy;
        std::memcpy(MUserPtr, HostPtr, MSizeInBytes);
      }
    }
  }
```

And [ComputeCpp documentation explicitly mentions pinned memory when discussing `use_host_ptr`](https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/2.11.0/guides/sycl-for-cuda-developers/memory-model#sycl-pinned-memory):

> There are generally two ways which host memory can be allocated:
>
> - When not using the `cl::sycl::property::buffer::use_host_pointer` property, the SYCL runtime will allocate host memory when required. This uses the implementation-specific mechanism, which can attempt to request pinned memory.

ComputeCpp itself is getting deprecated, but the idea is still valid, and is not CUDA-specific.

Note: ComputeCpp webpage says "There is no explicit mechanism to request pinned memory in SYCL," which is no longer true: `sycl::malloc_host` will do that just fine. While the SYCL2020 standard does not directly say that, but it guarantees that the memory allocated with `sycl::malloc_host` should be accessible from the device, which strongly implies pinning.